# Numbering of appendices and blank pages missing between appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, thesis, blank-page

I am trying to make the appendices to my Master's thesis. The template consists of several parts that are arranged in a file called "final.tex". I'm having two problems with appendices:

1. I can keep the index the way I want it, but appendices A, B and C instead of starting with A.1, B.1 and C.1 start with A.1, A.1 and A.1 always, regardless of the letter of the appendices. I want the title of the appendices: "Anexos A", "Anexos B" and "Anexos C" not to have a letter in front, but that the subtitles have a letter, the dot and the number.
2. The blank pages added in the appendices are not being assumed. When the number of pages is odd, the template is not putting a blank page in the appendices, as it does with the rest of the document.

How can I resolve these two issues? I've tried to see other Stack Exchange questions and tried to see if it worked, but I still haven't been able to get the template to work properly.

Code of the "final.tex" file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
%oneside ou openany serve para tirar paginas em branco depois das secções
% Omitting Page Numbers
\pagenumbering{gobble} 

% Packages
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4.9cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\usepackage{graphicx,kantlipsum,setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font={stretch=1,footnotesize}, labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=1,footnotesize}, labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools,float,geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,tabularx,threeparttablex}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}
%\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{afterpage}  % blank pages
\usepackage{multirow}  % table
%\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}  % table
\usepackage{xpatch}  % table
\usepackage{tabu}  % table
\usepackage{hhline}  % cell color does not overlap cell line
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % headers
\usepackage{breakcites}  % references do not go though margins
\usepackage{sectsty}  % change chapter title size
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  % four level contents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  % numbered four level contents
\usepackage{amsfonts}  % math
\usepackage{amsmath}  % math
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % references
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newlength\bshft
\bshft=.18pt\relax
\def\fakebold#1{\ThisStyle{\ooalign{$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
  \kern-\bshft$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
  \kern\bshft$\SavedStyle#1$}}}
\newlength\longest
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unchapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makechapterhead\@gobble % make \@makechapterhead do nothing
  \chapter{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem
  []% init options
  {definição}% name
  {Definição}% title
  {%
    colback=gray!5,
    colframe=gray!20!gray,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
  }% options
  {def}% prefix
%\newcommand{\rectangle}{{  % rectangle
%  \ooalign{$\sqsubset\mkern3mu$\cr$\mkern3mu\sqsupset$\cr}
%}}

%\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}

% References
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks=true,
   linkcolor=black,
   filecolor=black,
   citecolor=black,
   urlcolor=black,
   bookmarksopen=true,
   linktocpage=true,
   pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
   pdfstartpage=1
}

% Blank Page
\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage}

% Hide Blank Pages Numbers + Headers
\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
  \clearpage
  {\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}%
}

% Space between numbers and text
\geometry{footskip=1.2cm}

\begin{document}
\begingroup

\newgeometry{left=3cm, right=3cm, top=1cm, bottom=1.2cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.9}

%\include{parts/capa_provisoria}
\include{parts/capa_definitiva}

\afterpage{\blankpage} %comentar para tirar paginas em branco

\endgroup

% Preamble for Thesis
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newgeometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage  % hide blank pages numbers + headers

\include{parts/agradecimentos}
%tenho um problema com a numeração das paginas
%%\afterpage{\blankpage}
\include{parts/dedicacao}
%%\afterpage{\blankpage}
\include{parts/abstract}

\include{parts/resumo}

%\include{parts/resumo_alargado}

\include{parts/contents}

\include{parts/list_of_figures}

\include{parts/list_of_tables}

\afterpage{\blankpage} %comentar para tirar paginas em branco

% After Introductory Pages
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newgeometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,headsep=1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt} 

\chaptertitlefont{\Huge} % to fit chapter title to one line
\chapternumberfont{\Huge} 

\include{parts/introducao}

\include{parts/propriedadesTMDs}

\include{parts/aplicacoes}

\include{parts/metodosexperimentais}

\include{parts/resultadosediscussao}

\include{parts/conclusao}

\pagestyle{plain}  % no more header 

\include{parts/bibliografia}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{section}}
\include{parts/AnexosA}

\include{parts/AnexosB}

\include{parts/AnexosC}
\end{document}
```

Appendix A part code:

```
%\newpage
\appendix
\section*{\Huge Anexos A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anexos A}
%\chapter*{Anexos A}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anexos A}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{A.\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\vspace{1cm}
\section{Diferença de caminho óptico}
```

Appendix B part code:

```
\newpage
\appendix
\section*{\Huge Anexos B}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anexos B}
%\chapter*{Anexos A}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anexos A}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\theequation}{B.\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\vspace{1cm}
\section{Distribuição log-normal}
```

Table of contents:
[image]

Errors with parts "Anexos A" and "Anexos B":

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are resetting the numbering by using `\appendix` multiple times.
Try using it before the whole appenix part only, like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \Blinddocument

    \appendix

    \refstepcounter{chapter}
    \chapter*{\appendixname\enskip\thechapter}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname\enskip\thechapter}
    
    \section{Section in Appendix A}

    \refstepcounter{chapter}
    \chapter*{\appendixname\enskip\thechapter}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname\enskip\thechapter}

    \section{Section in Appendix B}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect. It worked! Thanks for the help!